# container used to obfuscate vsts build artifacts in release pipeline as VSTS task

Tags: azure-devops, containers

I asked this question in the devops stack exchange [link to question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/4033/3062) but wanted to try to reach out to another community that might be able to help answer the question.

I would like to have a container image in the cloud running a tool installed on the image.  During my VSTS release pipeline, I would like for my release agent to pull down this image, pass in the build artifact, and then do something with the results of running my artifact through this tool.  I have an Azure subscription.  I've tried reading the documentation but I'm confused as to what I need to set up.  This container is not hosting any web app, but is being used as a way to run my tool locally on the release agent.  I see that I can run a docker run command as a VSTS pipeline action.  What do I need to set up on my azure subscription to host this image for the VSTS agent to pull it down?

Comment: Asking for tool or off-site resource recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow, so I would expect that this question will be closed as off-topic. That said, I don't see what the point of obfuscation is in your scenario. Anything that's obfuscated can be de-obfuscated, and if your staging or production environments are compromised to the extent that an attacker has copied your de-obfuscatable application, you have **way bigger** problems.

Comment: to play devils advocate, all encryption can be reversed as well (give time/resources), that isn't to point of the question.  I did edit my question be be more direct and to remove any ambiguity as to what i'm trying to achieve.  I want to use Azure as my image store to host an image not to run on azure but to be pulled down and ran on a vsts agent.  How do i create the store?  How do i get an image in this store?  Can this even be done using Azure?

Comment: I'm just seeing a request to help implement a fairly complicated solution to what appears to be a non-problem, which is something I feel compelled to comment on.  Back to the topic at hand, "How do I use Azure containers in VSTS?" is way too broad for this site -- your question is still off-topic even with the edits. To point you in the right direction, what you're looking for is the Azure Container Registry. That allows you to create a container registry to which you can push your custom container images. That should give you a good starting point for independent research.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: I think that the azure container registry would be the best solution for the problem described.  However, I was am able to solve the core problem by uploading the tool to source control and downloading it as an artifact alongside the artifacts I wanted to obfuscate (as per the instructions of the tool developer).  So I no longer needed to use container to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the image through Dockerfile, for example: [dotnetcore-docker-sample](https://github.com/adventworks/dotnetcore-docker-sample/blob/master/Dockerfile), after checking Dockerfile, you can find that it copies the build result to image and set the ENTRYPOINT, so the web app can be run when run that image.

So, you can build the image through Docker task (Action: Build an image), then push the image through Docker task too (Action: Push an image; Specify Azure subscription and Azure Container Registry).

Regarding run the image, you can use Docker task too (Action: Run an image).

There is a blog that can help you: [Build, push and run Docker images with Visual Studio Team Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/08/19/build-push-and-run-docker-images-with-visual-studio-team-services/)